# How can I make a local file as body of an HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, post, curl, httpwebrequest, webrequest

For example:

I have to post data according to this [reference](http://developer.doreso.com/doc3.html#4)
They ask to post a request with a local file as the body.

The curl they suggest is: `curl -i --data-binary @test.mp3 http://developer.doreso.com/api/v1`

But how can I do the same in c#?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `HttpWebRequest` class and send file in a `multipart/form-data` request.

Here is a sample code that you may use with some modifications.

First read the contents of the file:

```
byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.mp3");
```

Then prepare the `HttpWebRequest` object:

```
string url = "http://developer.doreso.com/api/v1";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;
```

Send the file as body request:

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{ 
    requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

Read the response then:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Use the response if you need:

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Do not [commit plagiarism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087028/upload-multiple-files-in-a-single-httpwebrequest), especially when that code doesn't work (and yes, I saw you ninja-edit the similarities out). You also don't want to read the entire file in a byte array at once.

Comment: a quick look at the docs says the Content-Type should be "application/octet-stream", not "multipart/form-data"